# Encapsulating property and interface in C#

Tags: c#, properties, interface, encapsulation

I have a class:

```
public class A
{
    private IB link;
    public IB Link
    {
        get { return link; }
        set
        {
            link = value;
            b.Link = this;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

and an interface:

```
public interface IB
{
    A Link { get; set; }
}
```

I will use it like this:

```
public class B1 : IB, Button
{
    public A Link { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class B2 : IB, TextBox
{
    public A Link { get; set; }
    ...
}

b1 = new B1();
b2 = new B2();

A a = new A();
a.Link = b1;
...
a.Link = b2;
```

But I have to encapsulate the `IB.Link` property, it should changed only in the `A` class (along with the `A.Link` property). Is this possible?

**Update:**

Sorry for ambiguity of this example. My real code is too large and not finished: I have a structure of nodes. Each node has a link to Control. So, visual structure of controls can be constructed. We can manage the controls from nodes, but not get access to node from control, for example, from OnMouseClick method. We need have back reference - the IMyControl.OwnerNode property. IMyControl is interface that contains only this property. So, we can create "MyControl : IMyControl, Control" class and implement into it mouse click logic. When we assign control to node, both references must be created, direct and back, but it take place in code of node class, not in MyControl and IMyControl code. Property field in IMyControl interface must be accessible for write from NodeClass and unaccessible for write from derived classes. That i am trying to accomplish here.

Comment: what is  b.Link in Class A?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is quite unclear. What *exactly* do you mean by "*But I have to encapsulate the IB.Link property, it should changed only in the A class (along with the A.Link property).*"? Can you give an example in code?

Comment: How would you use b1.Link and b2.Link in your example? They left uninitialized.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use this draft:

```
class Node
{
    public ControlWrapper Link { get; set; }
}

abstract class ControlWrapper
{
    private readonly Node _node;
    private readonly Control _control;

    public Node Node
    {
        get { return _node; }
    }

    public Control Control
    {
        get { return _control; }
    }

    public ControlWrapper(Node node, Control control)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("node");

        if (control == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("control");

        _node = node;
        _control = control;
    }
}

class ControlWrapper<TControl> : ControlWrapper
    where TControl : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    public TControl Control
    {
        get { return (TControl)base.Control; }
    }

    public ControlWrapper(Node node, TControl control)
        : base (node, control)
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node n1 = new Node();
        n1.Link = new ControlWrapper<TextBox>(n1, new TextBox());
        Node n2 = new Node();
        n2.Link = new ControlWrapper<Button>(n2, new Button());
    }
}
```

Abstract class ControlWrapper provides you with back-link to node (you can't encapsulate logic in interface, so abstract class goes here), typed derived generic class provides constructor for creating actual implementations of control-wrappers.

If you want this relation automatically force its consistency, you should write code like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node n1 = new Node();
        n1.SetControl(new TextBox());
        Node n2 = new Node();
        n2.SetControl(new Button());
    }
}

class Node
{
    private ControlWrapper _link;
    public ControlWrapper Link
    {
        get { return _link; }
    }

    public void SetControl<TControl>(TControl control)
        where TControl : System.Windows.Forms.Control
    {
        ControlWrapper prevLink = Link;
        if (prevLink != null)
            prevLink.Dispose();

        _link = new ControlWrapper<TControl>(this, control);
    }
}

// microsoft basic dispose pattern
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx#basic_pattern
abstract class ControlWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Node _node;
    private readonly Control _control;

    public Node Node
    {
        get { return _node; }
    }

    public Control Control
    {
        get { return _control; }
    }

    public ControlWrapper(Node node, Control control)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("node");

        if (control == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("control");

        _node = node;
        _control = control;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_control != null)
                _control.Dispose();
        }
    }

}

class ControlWrapper<TControl> : ControlWrapper
    where TControl : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    public TControl Control
    {
        get { return (TControl)base.Control; }
    }

    public ControlWrapper(Node node, TControl control)
        : base (node, control)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, but I thought it would be easier, without using wrappers. Maybe not use a back link? I want to just be able to change the node by UI events of its control, this feedback - the whole point of the project.

Comment: I think that the easiest way of modifying your node objects according to its control events is to subscribe appropriate event handlers of your node to control when you make a link, and unsubscribe them when the link is no longer needed (link with another control has done or when object is disposing).